# SSRS - ReportingService2005.FireEvent - Generate Events permission, where is it?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, sqlclr

I'm currently writing a CLR Stored Procedure on a Report Server to fire my subscription event. I am unable to use FireEvent as an error is thrown stating user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' does not have the permissions. I know the permission I am looking for is Generate Event but I can't find it for the life of me.

Here is my error and CLR Stored Procedure, any help would be appreciated.

The stored procedure is on the Report Server. Report Server uses windows authentication. I have full admin rights on SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1).

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void CTest()
    {
        ReportingService2005 rs = new ReportingService2005();
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        rs.Url = "http://erer332/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx";
        Subscription[] lSubs;
        try
        {
            lSubs = rs.ListSubscriptions("/WFM Graphical Reports/Sales Order Formats by Company", null);
            rs.FireEvent("TimedSubscription", lSubs[0].SubscriptionID);
        }
        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(e.Detail.InnerXml);
        }
    }
};



<ErrorCode xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
    rsAccessDenied
</ErrorCode>
<HttpStatus xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
    400
</HttpStatus>
<Message xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
    The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' are insufficient for performing this operation.
</Message>
<HelpLink xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsAccessDenied&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=10.50.2500.0
</HelpLink>
<ProductName xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
    Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services
</ProductName>
<ProductVersion xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
    10.50.2500.0
</ProductVersion>
<ProductLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
   127
</ProductLocaleId>
<OperatingSystem xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
    OsIndependent
</OperatingSystem>
<CountryLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
    1033
</CountryLocaleId>
<MoreInformation xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
    <Source>
        ReportingServicesLibrary
    </Source>
    <Message msrs:ErrorCode="rsAccessDenied" msrs:HelpLink="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsAccessDenied&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=10.50.2500.0" xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
        The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' are insufficient for performing this operation.
    </Message>
</MoreInformation>
<Warnings xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices" />`
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright figured it out. Had to remote into the Reporting Services server and use SSMS from there to connect. I then could grant the necessary permissions from there. From my computer on SSMS I was looking around forever in the Report Server for the permissions and could not see Reporting Services.

Confusing!